# Excel macro deleting pattern of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating a macro that when standing in cell A, it deletes the value in the cells I have marked X below (leaving the cells marked O). The actual cells can contain any value.

```
A X X X
X O X X
X X O X
X X X O
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can the `O` be anywhere or will be always be like you have shown above?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I want to save the diagonal and delete the rest.

Comment: Always a 4x4 block or not? If it is, just record yourself doing it...

Comment: @AakashM No, it's arbitrary but always quadratic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub go_sub()

    Dim tmpRNG As Range
    Set tmpRNG = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion 'or you could set other range definition here, like Range("A1:d4")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In tmpRNG
        If cell.Row <> cell.Column Then cell.ClearContents
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**EDIT** The code above works for current region which starts in cell A1.

The code below works for any selected region:

```
Sub go_sub()

    Dim tmpRNG As Range
    Set tmpRNG = Selection
    Dim tmpOff As Long

        tmpOff = tmpRNG.Row - tmpRNG.Column

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In tmpRNG '.Cells
        If cell.Row - tmpOff <> cell.Column Then cell.ClearContents
    Next cell
End Sub
```

One Tip: if you have a large are do work with switch off screen updating, possibly turn off events, too.

Comment: This works great if the diagonal is at a1, b2, ... but how do I make it count cells relative to the active cell? Also it would be nice to use Set tmpRNG = Selection.

Comment: If the op wants to start in say `B1` this would not work as the `row <> column`

Comment: @glh, I've just added additional solution which works for any selected range.

Answer (score 2):

The following will take your current cell and delete all but the diagonals, Select the top left cell and all diagonals will stay... But I like KazJaw's answer.

```
Sub go_sub()

'get the range from current cell to the end 
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, ActiveSheet.Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol))

'set the next cell to keep as current one
Set Nextcell = selection

'cycle throug all cells in the range
For Each cel In  myRange

    'if the cell is to be kept?
    if cel.address = nextcell.address then
        'Reset the next cell to save BUT DONE CLEAR THECURRENT CELL
        set Nextcell = Nextcell.offset(1,1)
    Else
        'clear current cell if not to be saved
        Cel.clearcontents
    End if
Next
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Comment: your works for a selected range an mine works if you select the first cell only

Comment: after all, competition is good, +1 for interesting alternative :) hope to see you soon round here

Comment: Aggree. Discussion, friendly competition, inspiration and invention breeds knowledge. I like your answer better than mine, just don't want to say it ;) see you around also.